How to share a folder stored on an external USB drive?
I am struggling to get share a folder that is stored on a USB drive connected to my 2019 Mac running Sonoma 14.5.
I have added the folder via System Settings > General > File Sharing > i and assigned access to my account.
From a windows computer, if I go to \\my-imac\ in Windows Explorer I am asked for my user credentials after which I can see all the shares on my Mac listed including the one on the USB drive.  However, I cannot open this folder without getting an error message.  Shares stored elsewhere on this Mac open no problem.
I've also tried accessing the share from a Linux computer, but getting the same issue.
I thought this might be related to APFS, but I created a share for a folder on another USB drive formatted with MacOS Extended and get exactly the same issue.
Additional info: I get the following error message in Windows when trying to open affected shares:

\\computer-fqdn\share is unavailable. If the location is on this PC,
make sure the device or drive is connected or the disc is inserted,
and then try again. If the location is on a network, make sure you’re
connected to the network or Internet, and then try again. If the
location still can’t be found, it might have been moved or deleted.

On trying to access the share from a Linux client I get the following error message:

Connection failed for the given details: SMB mount failed with the error: mount error(2): No such file or directory.
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg).


What is the error message that you're getting?

\computerfqdn\share is unavailable. If the location is on this PC, make sure the device or drive is connected or the disc is inserted, and then try again. If the location is on a network, make sure you’re connected to the network or Internet, and then try again. If the location still can’t be found, it might have been moved or deleted.

Not very helpful.  Note that I can get to a different share on the Mac no problem, so it isn't an issue with name resolution or reachability. It's just shares stored on external USB drives.

@Allan I would expect there to be some logging on the Mac showing failed attempts to reach the share that might give some clues, but I don't know where to look for that.

First, try checking the permissions of your USB drive. Second, you could try granting Full Disk Access for "smbd" (/usr/sbin/smbd) (SMB daemon) in Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Full Disk Access.

@Aeronautix granting smbd Full Disk Access did the trick.  Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Try granting Full Disk Access for smbd (/usr/sbin/smbd) (SMB daemon) in System Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Full Disk Access.
If you don't already see smbd in your System Settings, you can add it by doing the following:

Click the "+" sign at the bottom.
Authenticate.
Do Command + Shift + g and type /usr/sbin/smbd, hit enter and open it.

Links about not being able to remotely access macOS external drives, all from macOS Catalina era:

SMB connection to external Thunderbolt drive not working in MacOS Catalina - Apple SE
What causes some Network Drives using SMB no longer connect to macOS Catalina? - Apple SE
Can't connect to mounted USB drives over network after Catalina upgrade - Apple Discussions
Not able to access external drives via SMB on Mac OS Catalina - Apple Discussions

